# android http request doesn't work on android device or android emulator

Tags: ionic-framework

so i just created this ionic app, and I put a http request method on it for test, the problem is win I build the app for android the http method doesn't work. 
But it works fine win a build it for iOS,

This is my ionic info:

```
  ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.6.0 (/Users/us/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.5
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.2

   Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms     : android 8.0.0, ios 5.0.1
   Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic 5.3.1, cordova-plugin- 
   ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.1, (and 6 
   other plugins)
```

System:

```
 ios-sim : 8.0.1
   NodeJS  : v10.15.1 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm     : 6.9.0
   OS      : macOS High Sierra
   Xcode   : Xcode 10.1 Build version 10B61
```

my page.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import "rxjs/add/operator/map"



@Component({
selector: 'page-home',
templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
list_car:any;

 constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public http: Http) {
//check if the omra section exist or not

this.http.get("http://android.page.com/2omra_details.php")
.map(res 
=> res.json().omra)
.subscribe(data => {
    this.list_car = data;
    console.log(this.list_car); 


})

}

}
```

Any suggestions to what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post your code please

Comment: @Velu Dhanesh i added my code in my post Thanks

Comment: https://www.joshmorony.com/an-introduction-to-http-requests-fetching-data-in-ionic/

Answer (score 0):

Your endpoint not working

Try with sample data API [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular5-http-example?file=app%2Fapi.service.ts)

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/retry';

@Injectable()
export class ApiService {

  url: string = 'https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random';
  url2: string = 'https://api.spacexdata.com/v2/launches/latest';
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getData(): Observable<ApiResponse> {
    return this.http.get<ApiResponse>(this.url).retry(3);
  }

  getOtherData(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get<any>(this.url2).retry(3);
  }
}

export interface ApiResponse {
  icon_url: string;
  id: string;
  url: string;
  value: string;
```